# How to pick a single element from an embedded array with the official C# driver. Best practice?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Given this doc form a collection of Courses I would like to pick a
single participant object from the embedded array

```
{
    _id: someCourseId,
    CourseName: "someName",
    Participants[
        {UserId: X Name: "person1"},
        {UserId:Y, Name:"person2"},
        {UserID:Z, Name:"person3"}
    ]
}
```

How do I write a query with the official C# sharp driver that only
returns the embedded array Element with userID Y ?

Right now I can select the Courses having a Participant with id Y
using Query.EQ("Participants.UserId",Y) and I can select to only get
the Participants field of the Course object using
SetFields("Participants"), but if this array is huge, I don't want to
fetch an entire array, but only a single element. Is this possible?

If not, then I would consider it best practice to not use embedded
arrays in cases where fetching specific elements are required.
Instead a separate collection should be used to hold the array values
and a "foreign key to the root doc"  (like you would do in a RDBMS).
That is, in my example I would create a Participants collection, where
each doc holds  the id of a Course. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [slice](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) like this:

```
 // it will skip 0 elements and load only one element from nested array
 var slice = Fields.Slice("Participants", 0, 1);
```

Also, i guess you know that mongodb always return root document, but you can change content of this documents by specifying fields you want load and size of nested array.

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of MongoDB it's not possible to do this. Like you say you'd have to split it into two collections with a reference. I've had to do this before due to other limitations of embedded arrays, such as not being able to sort them in the query.